# Which protocol does my Asus EeePC T101MT Wi-Fi support?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have an [Asus EeePC T101MT](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_T101MT/specifications/) with an Atheros ar9285 Wi-Fi device. I recently replaced my router with an “802.11n”-standard, but the only device which is still has slow Wi-Fi connection is this Asus. Probably, its Wi-Fi standard is only “802.11b” one, but I cannot clarify it. On the Internet Atheros ar9285 listed as supporting “802.11n” technology too (like “802.11b/g/n”)' probably there are some different versions of this card.

**Could you please advise how can I know exactly if my Asus’s Wi-Fi is 802.11n-compatible?**

This is the picture from hardware details:

[image]

For those who downvoted the question. Please, spend 1 minute to understand the question. There are multiple versions on the wifi card mentioned in the question.

Comment: The [specifications for your EeePC](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_T101MT/specifications/) state it has 802.11 a/b/g/n@2.4GHz.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Could you comment the specifications on the screenshot provided? I searched the Internet for a long time to realize that a/b/g/n means - "can support all or only one of these in different PCs and countries". The question is - How can I know the exact standard of my card...

Comment: Perhaps you actually want to ask a different question? Like how to fix this device's wireless performance issues.

Comment: @DanielB I just want to know which protocol actually works on the device. I did not ask what other site say about specs :)

Comment: the picture in your question has 2 mentions of 11n - case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please advise how can I know exactly if my Asus’s Wi-Fi is 802.11n-compatible?

Go to the web page for the manufacturer and check. You'll see that it is 802.11n-compatible. You can also tell by your image -- a device that can't support 802.11n wouldn't have any settings for AdHoc 11n.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer cannot address the issue. I know the specs... and I know that some of them could be disabled because of authorities' demands in some countries (try to realize which one)... The question was - how can I provide an experiment and to know exactly which protocol my wifi card supports.

Comment: @Ilan It sounds like there are two questions here, one that you asked and one that you want answered. Your question doesn't say anything about authorities or experiments.

Comment: the question was how to know which protocol my wifi card has. I did not ask what the specs on the some sites say....

Comment: @Ilan The way you tell what protocols a device supports is by checking the specifications. It really is the most reliable way.